# XPath expression working well in evaluator, but not in browser

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I can't get the browser's XPath evaluator to work, which is very frustrating. I'm pretty sure this is a namespace issue, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have an [XML document](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PghFrankenstein/fv-data/master/variorum-chunks/fMS_C09.xml). I want to execute an XPath query, even a simple one - `//teiHeader`. This is a valid query - returning all elements with the `teiHeader` tag. The document contains one such element.

Once I parse the XML document, I try to evaluate the XPath expression like so:

```
const resolver = doc.createNSResolver(doc.documentElement);
const xpathResult = doc.evaluate(xpath, doc, resolver);

let node = xpathResult.iterateNext();
while(node) {
    console.log(node);
    node = xpathResult.iterateNext();
}
```

The result is no nodes, the first call to `iterateNext` returns null.

You can look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmbq/mfx5hoav/30/) that demonstrates the problem. You'll see the XPath evaluation returned no elements, but a simple `getElementsByTagName` succeeds. Both Chrome and Firefox behave the same way.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TEI document you are using as source XML contains only a default namespace with no prefix. But in XPath 1.0, you must specify a prefix for each namespace you want to use. The XPath `//teiHeader` instead will only select `<teiHeader>` elements in no namespace.

If you want to retrieve the `teiHeader` element with `Document.evaluate()`, you can use this XPath instead:

```
const xpath = "//*[local-name() = 'teiHeader']"
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4Lnutae/)

Comment: So basically the web-based evaluator is the cause of my confusion, I thought this was a valid XPath. Blah on them.

Comment: Your XPath is valid, it just has a slightly different meaning in XPath 1.0 than in XPath 2.0. This difference is easy to overlook indeed. See also http://www.jenitennison.com/2007/07/01/the-perils-of-default-namespaces